# Use awk to extract a row records not contain specific word

Tags: shell, awk

Say my input file is table delimited, how do i identify if $0  doesn't contains a word "hello"?

1. here is a hello
2. hi i'm SS
3. hello this is Mr.Been.
4. I'm Rock in Java

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean tab delimited right? You can do this in awk:

```
awk '!/hello/' file
```

That command will print all records where `$0` does not contain `"hello"`.

**PS: If you want to match full word hello but avoid matching helloed then use:**

```
awk '!/(^|\y)hello(\y|$)/' file
```